# mage::getModel('module/model')->getData returns an empty array

Tags: configuration, model, resource-model

I am trying to pull data from a table. To do this I have used

`mage::getModel('module/model')->getData`

this has returned an empty array, but i can't work out why as the table i am calling holds data.

There is a discrepancy between this model

```
class Ps_Prefs_Model_Prefsformelements
extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('ps_prefs/prefsformelements');
}

}

class Ps_Prefs_Model_Resource_Prefsformelements
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('ps_prefs/prefsformelements', 'idform_elements');
}
}

class Ps_Prefs_Model_Resource_Prefsformelements_Collection
extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('ps_prefs/prefsformelements');
}
}
```

and other models in my module. That descripency lies in the `namespace_module/...` part of the call. as you can see this model uses `namespace_module/...` while my other models work fine with just `module/...` I have tried run the above code using just `module/...` but I get the error `can't retrieve entity config` but if I try to run the other using this `namespace_module/...` I start throwing errors why?

I had considered my config but if that is the case why am I not getting errors when I use `namespace_module/...` and why wont it work when I make it conform to the other models?

===

EDIT

===

```
<config>
...
  <global>        
    <models>
        <prefs>
            <class>Ps_Prefs_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>prefs_resource</resourceModel>
        </prefs>

        <prefs_resource>
            <class>Ps_Prefs_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <prefs>
                    <table>prefcentre</table>
                </prefs>
                <prefsemail>
                    <table>prefcentre_options</table>
                </prefsemail>
                <prefsform>
                    <table>pref_form_elements</table>
                </prefsform>
            </entities>
        </prefs_resource>
    </models>
  ...
</global>
...
</config>
```

Comment: did you call `load` before `getData`? `Mage::getModel('module/model')->load(3)->getData();`

Comment: I hadnt but now I have I get `function load() on a non-object`. What is wrong with the code for the model?

Comment: please paste the `config.xml` section where the models are defined. Everything between `<models></models>`

Comment: I assume you call your model like this `Mage::getModel('prefs/something_here')->load(3)`. Make sure the class `Ps_Prefs_Model_Something_Here` exists.

Comment: Sorry, I trying to make the question flow better, obviously I failed. I use `mage::getModel('prefs/prefsformelements')` to call the model and I have three files for it, the model, the resource model and the collection, which are what I've post above. could the discrepancy I mentioned have anything to do with the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you do not have a definition for the table `prefs/prefsformelements`. If you look at how the init for the resource works it takes the following:

```
/**
 * Standard resource model initialization
 *
 * @param string $mainTable
 * @param string $idFieldName
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract
 */
protected function _init($mainTable, $idFieldName)
{
    $this->_setMainTable($mainTable, $idFieldName);
}
```

So looking at this and your config.xml you are missing the table that matches `prefsformelements` but your have others that you might have mixed up the names for.

```
<prefsformelements>
    <table>pref_form_elements</table>
</prefsformelements>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Mage::getModel instead of mage::getModel.

Comment: That won't make a difference. Class names are not case sensitive in PHP and `Mage.php` file is not autoloaded. So you can use `Mage`, `mage`, even `mAgE`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I must have had my brain in Perl mode. :)